# R - Adjusting the value labels of the y-axis

Tags: r, graphics, axis-labels

I am working on creating a histogram in R for the built-in data set cars. I want to adjust the y-axis so that it reads c(0, "", 0.04, "", 0.08). However, I seem to be unable to do so.

I have tried to save the new label values as a list and then called that list in a text() function...
Furthermore, I tried the following:

```
    data(cars)

    hist(cars$speed,
      main = "",
      breaks = 11,
      xlab = "Speed",
      ylab = "Density",
      yaxt = "n",  
      freq = FALSE)
    axis(side=2,
      at = 1:5,
      labels = c(0, "", 0.04, "", 0.08), 
      las = 2,
      mgp = c(3, 2, 1))
```

To my mind, this should have worked but I do not get an output from the axis() function.
What did I do wrong?

PS: In addition to that, another error occurs when I accept the automatically generated y-axis aka by deleting yaxt="n". The y-axis value labels are printed on top of the y-axis label "Density". This should not be the case because of mgp[1]... What's the mistake here?

Comment: If you run `axis(side = 2)` to get the default axis, you'll see that, since you've set `freq = FALSE`, your histogram goes up to a maximum of about 0.08. So the y-axis you specify with tickmarks `at = 1:5` is way off the chart. Your plot goes from 0 to 0.08, but you are telling `axis()` to put the smallest tick value at `1`. The tickmarks need to have `at =` values that are within the limits of the plot. I'd suggest `at = c(0, 0.04, 0.08)` and **don't** override the default labels.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: see comments:**

```
hist(cars$speed,
     main = "",
     breaks = 11,
     xlab = "Speed",
     ylab = "Density",
     yaxt = "n",  
     freq = FALSE)

# Use mtext instead of text
mtext(side = 2, 
      at = seq(0, 0.08, by = 0.04),
      text = rev(c(0.04, "", 0.08, "", 0)), 
      line = 1, 
      las = 1, 
      col = "black", 
      cex = 1)

axis(side = 2, 
     at = seq(0, 0.08, by = 0.04), 
     labels = FALSE, 
     lwd = 1, 
     col = "black", 
     tck = -0.03, 
     lty = 1, 
     las = 1, 
     mgp = c(3, 2, -1))
```

[image]
**First answer:**
The reason you are not seeing the y-axis is `yaxt = "n"` (turned off y-axis). Here are two possible solutions:

**base R:**

```
hist(cars$speed,
     main = "",
     breaks = 11,
     xlab = "Speed",
     ylab = "Density",
     yaxt = "n",  
     freq = FALSE)

text(x = par("usr")[1] - 0.01 * diff(par("usr")[1:2]), 
     y = seq(0, 0.08, by = 0.04),
     labels = c(0, "", 0.04, "", 0.08), 
     xpd = TRUE, 
     adj = 1, 
     col = "black", 
     cex = 1)

axis(side = 2, 
     at = seq(0, 0.08, by = 0.04), 
     labels = FALSE, 
     lwd = 1, 
     col = "black", 
     tck = -0.02, 
     lty = 1, 
     las = 1, 
     mgp = c(3, 2, 0))
```

[image]

**ggplot**

```
library(ggplot2)
data(cars)

ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 11, color = "black", fill = "gray", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 0.04, 0.08), labels = c(0, 0.04, 0.08)) +
  labs(x = "Speed", y = "Density") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Sadly, I am not allowed to use the ggplot2 package...
I have two follow up questions on your code:
1. Weirdly, the y-axis labels are now in a wrong order. It reads 0 - 0.08 - 0.04.
2. I want tck = -1. To prevent the bars from overlapping with the value labels I adjusted   adj = 1 to   adj = 2. However, this only shifts the two upper values to the left and the bar still overlaps with 0.
What can I do to change these things?